# figure the chances of a specific subset of the population acquiring melanoma

Tags: probability

Given the following facts, what percentage of the ">100 moles" people have or had melanoma?

- 6% of the general population has > 100 moles on their body
- 18% of melanoma patients have > 100 moles on their body
- 0.3% prevalence of melanoma in the general population (people who have, or had, it)

Answer (score 1):

We do a formal conditional probability calculation.

Choose a person at random. Let $B$ be the event the person has $\gt 100$ moles on the body. Let $M$ be the event the person has/had melanoma. We want $\Pr(M|B)$.

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$\Pr(M|B)=\frac{\Pr(M\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}=\frac{\Pr(B|M)\Pr(M)}{\Pr(B)}.$$
We are told that $\Pr(B)=0.06$, $\Pr(B|M)=0.18$ and $\Pr(M)=0.003$. It follows that 
$$\Pr(B|M)=\frac{(0.18)(0.003)}{0.06}=0.009.$$
Thus the required probability is $0.9\%$.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume we have a population of 100,000 people, then 6000 people have many moles, 300 people have melanoma, and only 54 have melanoma and many moles.

Therefore the percentage of people with many moles who have had melanoma is given by $\frac{54}{6000}\cdot100=.9\%$.